# h : P(N) → P(N), where ∀A ∈ P(N): h(A) = N \A injective or surjective, or both?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

h : P(N) → P(N), where ∀A ∈ P(N): h(A) = N \A

I have been looking at this for a long time and I cannot work out how I would determine whether it is a surjective or injective function.

P(N) refers to a power set.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  As a hint to get started:  What is $h\circ h$?

Comment: Incomprehensible. What are $P,N,A$ and $N/A$ supposed to mean?

Comment: And $N$ is the natural numbers? and $N\setminus A$ is the complement of $A$ in $N$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decide whether $h$ is surjective, choose some arbitrary $B \in P(N)$, so in other words $B \subseteq N$. Then try to find some set $A \in P(N)$ such that $h(A) = B$. If you can always do that, you'll know $h$ is surjective. If not, $h$ is not surjective.

To decide whether $h$ is injective, choose some arbitrary sets $C,D \subseteq N$ and assume $C \not = D$. Now write down the definitions of $h(C)$ and $h(D)$ and try to prove $h(C) \not = h(D)$. If instead of a proof you end up finding a counterexample, then $h$ is not injective.